# CakePHP Mail Function Internal Error occured

Tags: cakephp-2.0

```
public $default = array(
        'transport' => 'Mail',
        'from' => 'krutarth@gmail.com',
        'charset' => 'utf-8'
        //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    );

    public $smtp = array(
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'from' => array('admin@example.com' => 'Project Name'),
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'krutarth@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'client' => null,
        'log' => false,
        'tls' => true
        //'charset' => 'utf-8',
        //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    );
```

I have this setting in my confing->email.php
on Error page I get formate of email as I defined so controller code is  but It says an Internal error occured...

Could not send email.

Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
Stack Trace

```
CORE/Cake/Network/Email/MailTransport.php line 47 → MailTransport->_mail(string, string, string, string, null)
CORE/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php line 1066 → MailTransport->send(CakeEmail)
APP/Controller/HomeController.php line 225 → CakeEmail->send(string)
[internal function] → HomeController->forgot()
CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 486 → ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(HomeController, array)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 187 → Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 162 → Dispatcher->_invoke(HomeController, CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
APP/webroot/index.php line 93 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

result of CORE/Cake/Network/Email/MailTransport.php line 47 -> MailTransport->_mail(string,string,string,string,null) is

aryan@*********.com'
'Password reset instructions from "App"'
'

Please click on the link to activate your account.

```
Click here to activate
```

Alternatively, you can also copy paste the below link into your browser:

http://application.com/user/activation/*************/

This email was sent by "App".

'From: krutarth.patel7@gmail.com
X-Mailer: CakePHP Email
Date: Mon, 05 Aug 2013 19:08:53 +0530
Message-ID: <*******@app,cm>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'
null

I need some help to solve this problem...I have tried Book.cakephp.org and some other question's answer on this site but no effect

I am using Cakephp2.3.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Error is because you haven't specified sender's account (Ex. admin@admin.com) in your controller.

Comment: Yes, that is right...I came to know it later. BTW thnx for your help

Answer (score 0):

I got tired of playing around and simply edited the CakePHP code to output $params array to see the raw reason for the error.  I did this by editing the ‘cake/libs/error.php’ file and adding the following around line 176 in the “error500″ function as the first two lines as follows:

```
print_r($params);
die();
```

This gave me a simple array that clearly informed me I was missing a table in the DB that was deprecated. From there I quickly found the entry in the model that was still trying to link to the deprecated table. I cleaned up the offending model, and now all is well with the world again.

[Read More](http://www.geekyboy.com/archives/341)